# Why doesn't my reset() function remove my red error lines?

Tags: javascript, html, function

```js
function validate() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "";
  if (checkfname() == true) {
    alert("Entry submitted.");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function checkfname() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  if (fname.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "Invalid first name. Cannot be empty.";
    return false;
  } else if (!isNaN(fname)) {
    document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "Invalid first name. Cannot contain numbers.";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function addRow() {
  if (validate() == true) {

  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  First Name:
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
  <p id="errorfname" class="red"></p>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Entry" onclick="return addRow()" />
  <input id="clear" type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset()" />
</form>
```

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for = "firstnameinput">
      First Name: <input type = "text" id = "fname" name = "fname" placeholder = "John"/>
      <p id = "errorfname" class = "red"></p>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label id = "submitbutton">
        <input id = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit Entry" onclick = "return addRow();upperCase();"/>
    </label>
    <label id = "resetbutton">
        <input id = "clear" type = "button" value = "Reset" onclick = "reset()"/>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my simplified HTML file. It basically has an input and a paragraph below it to display an error message later on. For now it is set as "" in javascript. The HTML also has a submit button and a reset button. The purpose of the reset button is to clear all previously entered fields or any error message that has appeared.

```
function validate(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "";
    if(checkfname() == true){
            alert("Entry submitted.");
        }
    else{
        return false;
    }

function checkfname(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if(fname.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "Invalid first name. Cannot be empty.";
        return false;
    }
    else if(!isNaN(fname)){
        document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "Invalid first name. Cannot contain numbers.";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

function addRow(){
    if(validate() == true){
        event.preventDefault();
        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        firstNameArray.push(fname)

    var row = document.getElementById('table').insertRow(-1);
    var colNum = row.insertCell(0);
    var colName = row.insertCell(1);

    i++;

    colNum.innerHTML = i;
    colName.innerHTML = fname + " " + lname;

    else{
        return false;
    }
    reset();
}
```

Lastly, my reset() function below.

```
function reset(){
    document.getElementById("errorfname").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
}
```

The problem is, for example, in the input box for fname, I enter John. When I press the reset button on my HTML which calls the reset() function, John in the box disappears so I got that going for me which is nice. However, lets say I purposely left the box blank to receive an error message, a red sentence below the box appears saying "Invalid first name. Cannot be empty." When I press the reset button to call onto the reset() function, this red error message does not disappear however, any current value inside the box disappears. This makes by reset() function work 50% only. I clearly stated for both to disappear in my reset() function.

TL;DR
I have a reset button in my HTML which calls a reset() function in my javascript. I have a name input box in my HTML and what the reset() function is supposed to do is to remove any current name which is inside the box as well as remove any error message that appears below. My reset() function is able to clear away any name inside the box currently but is unable to clear away the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a fiddle to test your problem. I noticed the same thing. I changed the method `reset()` to `resetTest()` and it worked fine.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ut7q5qst/)

The *reason* changing the name worked is that `onxyz=` attribute event handlers are run (effectively) within a couple of `with` statements, one of which is `with (theEnclosingFormElement)`. Form elements have a built-in `reset` method that clears all of their inputs to their initial values. So in this:

```
<input id = "clear" type = "button" value = "Reset" onclick = "reset()"/>
```

The `reset` being called isn't your `reset`, it's the *form's* `reset`, which doesn't (of course) do anything with `errorfname`. Changing the name removes the conflict.